# Save Google Authentication with GAPI & GSI

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using the [Google JavaScript quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js) to connect to the Calender API.

As in the example I use the http server on port 8000

```
npx http-server -p 8000
```

So http://localhost:8000 works as intended.

The example works as described and I can authenticate. Now I am looking for a way to save this authentication for the browser. But the solutions I have found do not work.

It seems this part should handle it, but `gapi.client.getToken()` is always null.

```
if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
        // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
        // when establishing a new session.
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
    } else {
        // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
    }
```

Then I tried to cache the access token.

```
function gisLoaded() {
    tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        callback: (tokenResponse) => {
            access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
       *** window.localStorage.setItem("access_token", tokenResponse.access_token);***
        },
    });
    gisInited = true;
    maybeEnableButtons();
}

function maybeEnableButtons() {
    if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
       *** if (window.localStorage.getItem('access_token') !== null) { ***
            access_token = window.localStorage.getItem('access_token');
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
            listUpcomingEvents()
        } else {
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }
}
```

But this token always seems to be "undefined" or "null". No matter where I call it.

`tokenResponse.access_token;`
`gapi.client.getToken();`
`tokenClient.requestAccessToken();`

All these calls don't seem to help me with my goal of having the browser authenticated with the API.

Google documentation doesn't help me much there either.
Am I missing something?
In some forums, there was also something about not working at all with localhost. Is there something to it? How else should I test such a program if not as very first on a local server?